# Stardog: Location of stardog.properties file

Tags: stardog

This must be a stupid question, because no one else has posted it and the explanation in stardog is very simple. It says 'Stardog Server’s behavior can also be configured via a stardog.properties—which is a Java Properties file—file in STARDOG_HOME.'

I am looking for the stardog.properties file. It is not in the folder I specified STARDOG_HOME to be. In fact, it is not anywhere. I have done a search of the entire computer.

What is going on?

*This question was answered below.

Comment: Below comment answers this question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no default stardog.properties file which is why you cannot find it. You can create the file yourself in the STARDOG_HOME folder. You can find an example configuration file in the [stardog-examples repo](https://github.com/stardog-union/stardog-examples/blob/develop/config/stardog.properties).